# jQuery animation repeating glitch

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, background-color

I have a set of inputs and I want to change their background color after hovering and then come back to the original color after mouse out.

It works fine, with one glitch. When I hover over those inputs, un-hover, and hover again, rapidly, they blink some time after. How can I fix it?

Here's my code:

```
    $("input").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#fff'}, 800);
},  function(){
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#666'}, 1400);
    });
```

(I don't want to change animate times)

I've found a working example:

http://veerle.duoh.com/ - check SEARCH input - when you hover and then take mouse very fast off - it doesn't finish animation or even blink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey, you must use `stop()` function to stop current animation, otherwise jquery will complete the animation stack (all other animations in queue) before starting your new... See [jQuery `queue()` function](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) docs to understand how jQuery FX works...

```
    $("input").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: '#fff'}, 800);
    },  function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: '#666'}, 1400);
    });
```

See [jQuery `stop()` function](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) docs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick tutorial on stoping jQuery from animation buildup.  I have used this technique on a number of occasions.

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup